# concatenate two matrices or dataframes cell-by-cell

Tags: r

I want to concatenate `df` and `p` as shown in the last step of my MRE. Any ideas?

```
# functions ----
  asterisk <- function(y) symnum(y, c(0, .001, .01, .05, .1, 1), 
                                 c("***", "**", "*", ".", " "))
  rd2 <- function(y) sprintf("%.2f", round(y, 2))
# packages ----
  require(foreign)
  require(nnet)
# example data from http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/mlogit.htm
  ml <- read.dta("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/hsbdemo.dta")
  ml$prog2 <- relevel(ml$prog, ref = "academic")
  test <- multinom(prog2 ~ ses + write, data = ml)
# get coefficients and round
  df <- data.frame(coefficients(test))
  df <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, rd2))
  row.names(df) <- row.names(coefficients(test))
  df
  #             X.Intercept.  sesmiddle seshigh write
  # general     2.85          -0.53     -1.16   -0.06
  # vocation    5.22          0.29      -0.98   -0.11
# get p-values
  z <- summary(test)$coefficients/summary(test)$standard.errors
  p <- matrix((1 - pnorm(abs(z), 0, 1)) * 2, nrow=nrow(z))
  p <- as.data.frame(apply(p, c(1,2), asterisk))
  #    V1 V2 V3  V4
  # 1   *     *  **
  # 2 ***     . ***
# concatenate df and p
  #             X.Intercept.  sesmiddle seshigh write
  # general     2.85*         -0.53     -1.16*  -0.06**
  # vocation    5.22***        0.29     -0.98.   -0.11***
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind overwriting the existing `df` with the concatenated data:

```
df[] <- lapply(1:ncol(df), function(col) paste0(df[,col],p[,col]) );
```

If not, you can assign a new variable from `df` (say `dfp`) and assign that.

Using the original `df` as a starting point for this task is useful because it prevents having to worry about setting/fixing dimension names.

Comment: you and @bergant both have good suggestions that work. i like `paste0`, so i'll select this one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use mapply to paste numbers with asterisks:

```
as.data.frame(
  mapply(FUN = paste, df, p),
  row.names = row.names(df)  
)
```

Comment: nice. I changed `paste` to `paste0` to get rid of the space.